# C# Forms read textBox1 all lines and delete given paths?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Good day!

I'm trying to create a C # Forms app where user chooses directories with FolderDialog and paths are saved in list.txt file after read by textBox1.
In list.txt user can add and delete path.

code snippet:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        }
string fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/etc/list.txt";

       private void LoadTextboxes()
        {
            string[] loadedLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/etc/list.txt");

            int index = 0;

            int n = int.Parse(loadedLines[index]);
            string[] lines = new string[n];
            Array.Copy(loadedLines, index + 1, lines, 0, n);
            textBox1.Lines = lines;
        }       
private void DeleteFilesFromDirectory(string directoryPath)
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);

            foreach (FileInfo fi in d.GetFiles())
            {
                fi.Delete();
            }

            foreach (DirectoryInfo di in d.GetDirectories())
            {
                DeleteFilesFromDirectory(di.FullName);

                di.Delete();
            }
        }

private void button1_Del(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteFilesFromDirectory(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

list.txt format:

```
C:/downloads
F:/doc/scan
D:/etc
```

t is important to delete only the sub folders and files but root folders must remain.
So far I have been done with my weak knowledge of c# and and now I'm stuck for a long time.
DeleteFilesFromDirectory only deletes the first line of textBox1.

How to make DeleteFilesFromDirectory read and delete all lines from textBox1?

Comment: So the root folder is downloads,doc,etc ?

Comment: If given path is F:/doc/scan, then need to be wiped everything under folder scan, but leave root folder scan empty

Answer (score 0):

Check this I tested it.

```
  //put all paths in array reading line by line
  string[] paths = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"path-to\list.txt");

  //get line by line paths
  foreach (string path in paths)
  {
        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            //deletes all files and parent
            //recursive:true, deletes subfolders and files
            Directory.Delete(path, true);
            //create parent folder
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

   }//end outer for
```